# Get IDs which don't have a specific value in other column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns : ID, value1, value2.
I want those IDs which don't have value1 equal to 'a' and 'b' at any point.

The dataframe df that I have :

```
ID   value1  value2
1    a      2
1    c      3  
1    e      4
2    f      5
2    g      10
3    b      7
3    e      8
```

The output that I have:

```
ID   value1  value2
2    f      5
2    g      10
```

As ID '2' doesnt have 'value1' as 'a' or 'b' in any record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by 'ID' and check if 'a' or 'b' is in group then invert selection (~) and select the right groups.

```
>>> df[~df['value1'].isin(['a', 'b']).groupby(df['ID']).transform('any')]

   ID value1  value2
3   2      f       5
4   2      g      10
```

**Optimized by @ALollz**

Answer (score 2):

No need groupby , try with `isin`

```
out = df.loc[~df.ID.isin(df.loc[df.value1.isin(['a','b']),'ID'])]
Out[212]: 
   ID value1  value2
3   2      f       5
4   2      g      10
```